# How are Vector Graphics Shown "Real-Time" as Raster Graphics?

Tags: vector-graphics

So my monitor is using raster graphics and is therefore full of pixels.

However, I have heard that Adobe Illustrator uses vector graphics.

So how can vector graphics be shown "real-time" on my monitor that is pixel-based?

From articles like [this one](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/computer-graphics.html), vector and raster graphics are completely different?  So why can the they show each other - like they were the same?

Comment: what do you mean by real-time?

Comment: @BooberBunz "How does computer turn a bunch of vectors into a lot of pixels, and at 60 Hz rate at that?"

Comment: I was asking @Fac Pam... since they asked the question, it's more important to know what they meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that Adobe Illustrator is a "vector program" only means that it is designed to help users work with vectors... just as Audacity, for example, helps users to work with sound, or Notepad lets a user work with characters.

There is no difference between Adobe Illustrator and any other program as far as what the Operating System (OS) and/or hardware expects from it in terms of the way it represents graphics.

Take these three examples:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

We can use the idea of a "+" symbol to show the difference between a raster and a vector:

RASTER: A 3 x 3 pixel, black-and-white RASTER of the "+" symbol:

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0
```

VECTOR: The same symbol as a Vector:

```
[draw a line from point ( 1/3 X, 1/2 Y ) to point ( 2/3 X, 1/2 Y )]
[draw a line from point ( 1/2 X, 1/3 Y ) to point ( 1/2 X, 2/3 Y )]
```

These are abstract representations -- they still need to be *coded*, *stored*, and *displayed*.

You can literally see how a raster is coded, stored, and displayed -- as a discrete matrix of values... a mosaic, if you will.

A vector on the other hand is coded and stored as a set of instructions.  The x and y co-ordinates are stored as fractions of the total canvas space available (relative as opposed to absolute)... as the dimensions of the canvas space are not yet known... and this is the reason why you can infinitely expand a vector without losing resolution.

Now... if a vector is going to be displayed on an actual "vector display" monitor (very rare), then you could theoretically just send the vector instructions straight to the monitor.  BUT... as you ask:  "What happens if you're displaying a vector on a conventional monitor (a mosaic of pixels)?"

And... the answer to that is, once again: The same thing that happens when any other abstract concept is being illustrated by any program.

But... the vectors do end up on the screen, so here is a minimal example of how that happens:

Using the "plus symbol" example from above, imagine a really terrible monitor that is only 3 x 3 pixels in resolution.  The OS would say to the program (Illustrator, presumably): "I need your raster output to be 3 x 3 pixels wide."

So the program would do this:

1) Draw a line from point ( 1/3 X, 1/2 Y ) to point ( 2/3 X, 1/2 Y )... but convert those points to points within that 3 x 3 pixel matrix... and draw the line by filling the first pixel, the last pixel, and all pixels in-between.

2) Do the same for the second instruction.

3) Hand the resulting 3 x 3 pixel matrix to the OS.

PS - You ask how they can "show each-other."  A conventional monitor can show a vector that has been converted to pixels, but I don't think it's ever been done the other way around.

Comment: So when using Adobe Illustrator on your computer are you constantly converting the vector graphics into raster graphics in order for the drawing to be shown on your pixel-based monitor? I mean, your monitor is divided into pixels whereas illustrator is using vector graphics?